# Using the chain rule of differentiation to evaluate an integral along a curve

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, line-integrals

I  have  a  little  confusion  regarding  the  following:

$\gamma $  is a  piecewise  smooth  curve from  $A$  to  $B$ and  $h(x,y)$  is  a  continuously  differentiable  function  on  $\gamma$.  Let  this curve  be  given  by  $$t\mapsto (x(t),y(t)),\text{ such that } t\in[a,b] .$$

Then $$\int_{\gamma}dh=\int_{\gamma}\left({{\partial h}\over {\partial x}}dx +{{\partial h}\over {\partial y}}dy\right)=\int_a^b{{\partial h}\over {\partial x}}{{d x}\over {d t}}dt + \int_a^b{{\partial h}\over {\partial y}}{{dy}\over {dt}}dt.$$

Upto  this  is  fine. Next  they  write: Using **chain rule ,** this  becomes  $$\int_a^b {{d}\over {dt}}h(x(t),y(t))dt.$$

This  step  is  not  clear  to  me because

$${{d}\over {dt}}[h(x(t),y(t))]={{dh}\over{dt}}|_{(x(t),y(t))}\left({{dx}\over {dt}},{{dy}\over {dt}}\right).$$ 
How  can  this  be  equal  to  the  above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got confused by the dimensions. The functions are
$$h:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}\\\gamma:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$$
and if you look closely on the theorem of the chain rule or better yet at the definition of multi-variable differentiation, you'll see how to use it correctly. Just do it step by step:

$$\begin{align}\frac{d}{dt}[h(x(t),y(t))]&=\frac{d}{dt}[h\circ \gamma](t)\\
&=Dh\mid_{\gamma(t)}D\gamma\mid_t\\
&=(\nabla h)^T\mid_{\gamma(t)}\frac{d}{dt}\gamma(t)\\
&=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}(\gamma(t)), &\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}(\gamma(t))\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\frac{dx}{dt}(t)\\\frac{dy}{dt}(t)\end{pmatrix}\\
&=\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}(\gamma(t))\frac{dx}{dt}(t)+\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}(\gamma(t))\frac{dy}{dt}(t)\end{align}$$

where in the second line I used a simple trick which prevents confusion when using the chain rule. $D$ denotes a general enough differentiation operator, to be specific the [Jacobian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) of which you probably should have heard (?). For a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ this is a $m \times n$ matrix. Just start by carefully writing down what the domains and codomains of your functions are, construct the Jacobian and it becomes quite hard to mess up chain rule ever again.